# Copying a Live Database without Log File

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 Database running on Express. I want to copy only the schema and data to an exact copy of this database. How can I do it and what are the steps involved?

My original database has a huge log file, so i do not want to copy that.

P.S: I do undersand that since this is a LIVE database, there could some amount of live data that will not be copied. I am OK with that.

Comment: its backed up every day but the log files is in the back up right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "Generate Scripts" option to create a sql file with all of your schema and data.  See this MS article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx